# Why would adding one additional INNER JOIN cause my execution time and result count to skyrocket?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2012

I was recently given access to a 3rd party database so I can display the data in presentations. I only have permissions to read data, I can't write or modify any tables or anything.

I'm trying to figure out why adding another table join is causing such huge ramifications on excution time and result size.

I have this query below that executes in less than a second and returns about 21,000 results.

```
SELECT *  
     
  FROM [dbo].[MODEL_OPTIONS] mo
  INNER JOIN [dbo].MANUFACTURER m ON mo.MANUFACTURER_ID = m.MANUFACTURER_ID
  INNER JOIN [dbo].DEALER_SALES ds ON mo.DEALER_MARKET_ID = ds.DEALER_MARKET_ID
  INNER JOIN [dbo].DEALER d ON ds.DEALER_ID = d.DEALER_ID
  WHERE m.countryID = 12
  AND ds.Sales IS NOT NULL
```

Now, I need to get some data from another table called DEALER_INFORMATION, so I added another `INNER JOIN` to `DEALER_INFORMATION`

```
   SELECT *  
     
   FROM [dbo].[MODEL_OPTIONS] mo
   INNER JOIN [dbo].MANUFACTURER m ON mo.MANUFACTURER_ID = m.MANUFACTURER_ID
   INNER JOIN [dbo].DEALER_SALES ds ON mo.DEALER_MARKET_ID = ds.DEALER_MARKET_ID
   INNER JOIN [dbo].DEALER d ON ds.DEALER_ID = d.DEALER_ID
   INNER JOIN [dbo].DEALER_INFORMATION di ON d.DEALER_ID = di.DEALER_ID  -- ** NEW JOIN ADDED
   WHERE m.countryID = 12
   AND ds.Sales IS NOT NULL
```

My excution time goes from less than a second to more than 30 seconds.

My result size goes from about 21k records to over 400k records.

I'm really confused by this because I thought using an `INNER JOIN` would only just get the data I needed.

Since I only have read permissions, I can't change anything.

Is there anyway to figure out why this is doing this to my query?

Thanks!

Comment: The usual cause is bad cardinality estimates from stale `STATISTICS` objects (when did you last update your `STATISTICS`?). The only way we can be sure is by looking at the plan, sooooooo **[POST THE PLAN!](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)**

Comment: Is this an ad-hoc query, or a query used repeatedly in production? If the latter, then **don't use** `SELECT *` because that wrecks everything: production-queries must always use explicitly named columns otherwise you'll invariably suffer performance losses because the DB server will need to read all matching rows from the tables instead of being able to use an indexes' `INCLUDE`ed columns.

Comment: Does DEALER_INFORMATION have an EAV structure ?

Comment: @Dai what is `bad cardinality`?  I don't think I have access to the plan

Comment: @Dai this is a query that will probably be used once a month or so...

Comment: Even if it's once a year, you should still be defining what columns you want, @SkyeBoniwell .

Comment: @JohnCappelletti is there a way I can determine that with a SELECT statement?  thanks!

Comment: @Larnu oh ok, so instead of just using `SELECT *` , let me try that to see if it works

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell `STATISTICS` and cardinality estimates are explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/statistics/statistics

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell You still need to post the plan. I assume you're using SQL Server Management Studio? If so, just click "Show **actual** execution plan" on the toolbar before you run your query (don't use the "Estimated execution plan" button though).

Comment: @Dai it does only say `Remote Query Cost: 100%'

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Do you have multiple records for each DEALER_ID in  DEALER_INFORMATION ?  For example a record for Street address and another for ZIP Code ?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti yes! I can see that with a SELECT statement! I just did and ordered by DEALER_ID and each DEALER_ID has multiple entries.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell So now you need to decide on what elements you want from DEALER_INFORMATION .   If this is truly an EAV structure . you may want to consider pivoting the results in a subquery.

Comment: @Dai thanks for the suggestions! I think I have figured this out now.  I will delete this question.  Thanks again! The disussion helped!

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thank you for all the info!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell **_Please_ do not** delete your question. Post whatever solution you found as your answer instead.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell ...and you still haven't posted your plan.